# Creating BATCH file with login, register and authentication features

Tags: batch-file

I really want to create login code in batch file that can authenticate users credentials, but by trying to google some stuff to make it work but i still can't, so i would like to ask some of professional coders, developers and programmers to help me and teach me about my mistakes since i'm still a student and newbie about programming.

Here's my code which is not authenticating after i created a new user and login in.

Please teach me well :<

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

MODE con: cols=51 lines=18
goto login

::Registration 
    :reg
        cls
        echo Create Account
        echo.
        set /p "uname=Username:"
        set /p "pass=Password:"
        
        echo Username: %uname% >> C:\Test\users.txt
        echo Password: %pass% >> C:\Test\users.txt

        goto login
        
::Login
    :login
        cls
        echo Please Login. To create new account type "new".
        echo.
        set /p "uname=Username:"
        if "%uname%"=="new" goto reg
        set /p "pass=Password:"
        
        call:authenticate
            
        goto succ
        
::Error
    :errorlogin
        cls
        echo Invalid credentials.
        pause >nul
        goto login
        
::Successful Login
    :succ
        cls 
        echo Login Successful
        pause >nul
        exit
        
::Copying/Backupping file and moving file after successful login
    :copy
        copy "C:\Users\userfile.sav" - "D:\Backup\"
        copy "C:\Users\userfile.sett" - "D:\Backup\"
        
        move "F:\unorthodox.exe" - "C:\Users\"
        
        goto done
        
::final
    :done
        echo     OOOOO    OOOO   O     O  OOOOO   O
        echo     O    O  O    O  O O   O  O       O
        echo     O    O  O    O  O  O  O  OOO     O
        echo     O    O  O    O  O    OO  O
        echo     OOOOO    OOOO   O     O  OOOOOO  O
        echo.
        echo     S  U  C  C  E  S  S  F  U  L  L  Y
        
        pause >nul
        
::====================================::
:authenticate
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (users.txt) do (
    if {%%a}=={%uname%}
    if {%%a}=={%pass%} )
    
    else
    goto errorlogin
```

and i would like to mask the password with asterisk so that it's more like secure, also i would like to add loading screen indicating about copy/moving progress.

so much very thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you having issues with the current code, or are you requesting additional code to compliment your current code?

Comment: Having an issue and requesting additional code for my current code

Comment: i'm having a trouble about logging in authentication with my existing user input.

Comment: I saw that part yes. let me have a look.

Comment: Take a look here ==> [Login and Register system in Batch File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44608074/login-and-register-system-in-batch-file?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: that's where did i get the idea of 
`if "%uname%"=="new" goto reg 
`
code. @Hackoo

Comment: echo user and password to one line `echo %uname% %pass% >> users.txt` then verify the user and password by searching for the string `for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in ('type users.txt ^| findstr /i "%uname%"`).. ` you can use `%%a` to verify username and `%%b` to verify password.

Comment: it's still not working sir @GerhardBarnard

this is what i did 

`for /f "tokens=1" %%a in (users.txt ^| findstr /i "%uname%") do (
    if {%%a}=={%uname%}
 if {%%b}=={%pass%} )
 
 else
 goto errorlogin ' 

_i also tried the_ 


for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in ('type users.txt ^| findstr /i "%uname%") do (
    if {%%a}=={%uname%}
    if {%%b}=={%pass%} )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working model of your code with some additional checks such as verifying a user does not already exist and ensure the user confirms password:

I would suggest you have a look at what rhe new layout is of your `users.txt` file after you create a user. So it would be best to clear the file and restart a new one `break>c:\test\users.txt`

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

MODE con: cols=51 lines=18
echo(
echo   ---------------------------------
echo ^| 1. Logon Existing Existing User^|
echo ^| 2. Create New User             ^|
echo   ---------------------------------
echo(
choice /C 12 /M "Please select: "
if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto login

::Registration 
    :reg
        cls
        echo Create User.
        echo(
        set /p "uname=Username: "
        for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`type "c:\test\users.txt" ^| findstr /i "'%uname%''"`) do (
            if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
               echo User already exists. Please enter new user. Press enter to retry.
               pause>nul
               goto reg:
        )
     )
        :setpass
        set /p "pass=Password: "
        set /p "conf=Confirm Password: "
        if not "%pass%" == "%conf%" (
          echo passwords do not match, please try again. Press enter to retry.
          pause>nul
          goto setpass
        )
        echo '%uname%''%pass%'>>"c:\test\users.txt"
        goto login
        
::Login
    :login
        cls
        echo Please Login.
        echo(
        set /p "uname=Username: "
        set /p "pass=Password: "
        
        goto authenticate
        
::Error
    :errorlogin
        cls
        echo Invalid credentials.
        pause >nul
        goto login
        
::Successful Login
    :succ
        cls 
        echo Login Successful
        pause >nul
        exit
        
::Copying/Backupping file and moving file after successful login
    :copy
        copy "C:\Users\userfile.sav" - "D:\Backup\"
        copy "C:\Users\userfile.sett" - "D:\Backup\"
        
        move "F:\unorthodox.exe" - "C:\Users\"
        
        goto done
        
::final
    :done
        echo     OOOOO    OOOO   O     O  OOOOO   O
        echo     O    O  O    O  O O   O  O       O
        echo     O    O  O    O  O  O  O  OOO     O
        echo     O    O  O    O  O    OO  O
        echo     OOOOO    OOOO   O     O  OOOOOO  O
        echo.
        echo     S  U  C  C  E  S  S  F  U  L  L  Y
        
        pause >nul
        
::====================================::
:authenticate
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`type "c:\test\users.txt" ^| findstr "'%uname%''%pass%'"`) do (
    if "%%a"=="'%uname%''%pass%'" (
       goto succ
   )
)
goto errorlogin
```

Comment: it always says successful login even though i didn't type any password :< 
so, i removed the 
`goto succ
`
and still not working.

Comment: It's WORKING! Thank you sir! now i will try to modify something in copy section.

Comment: sir? can i ask how can i hide or mask the password while typing it?

Comment: have a look at the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36291324/batch-file-command-hide-password/36292638) by SomethingDark. You can copy that code as is and make a few adjustments to your current code to let it call the password mask.

Comment: Thank you veru much sir! you really helped me a lot.